# Is it not possible to add HTML tags between ASP tags?

Tags: asp.net-3.5

I added a Web Form Content and linked it with Master Page. I could see in this Content Form that there is only one ContentPlaceHolder ASP tag. Now how to add DIV and other tags in between this?

Comment: On which page the master or the content form? ContentPlaceHolders are in Master pages; I guess I am a little confused with your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use HTML tags where ever in ASPX files. but its recommanded to use ASP.net tags (or maybe CSS for styling) if it is possible.